# jdbcTemplate nullable warning on not null field

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbctemplate, suppress-warnings, notnull

When calling select query on not null column so we can expect not null (int) value, Code:

```
public int getNum() {
    int num = 0;
    try {
        num = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select num from mytable", Integer.class);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ignored) {
        // ignored not found
    }
    return num;
}
```

Intellij warns:

`Unboxing of 'jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, Integer.class)' may produce 'NullPointerException'`

How can remove Intellij warning by marking value as not null?

I can't mark `jdbcTemplate` method as `@NotNullabe` or  use `@SuppressWarnings`

the value returns from SQL is always an int value that can't be null, I just want to indicate the IDE that value can't be null by its DB definition

Answer (score 1):

Statement `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select num from mytable", Integer.class);` returns instance of Integer.class, which may be `null`. Since your variable `num` is of primitive type `int`, a NullPointerException will occur during auto-boxing.

Solution:

```java
public int getNum() {
  int num = 0;
  try {
    Integer i = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select num from mytable", Integer.class);
    if(i != null) {
      num = i;
    }
  } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ignored) {
      // log or rethrow exception
  }
  return num;
}
```

Comment: But I can expect the column to return always a int value that is not null, I want to indicate the IDE that value can't be null by its DB definition

Comment: But it **could** be null from a technical perspective, as [queryForObject](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) returns an Object, not a primitive. And this includes null-references, even if - from a content perspective - the returned value **should** not be null.

Comment: Can you suggest how to return primitive? or disable this warning in this method?

Comment: See my answer above. It takes „null“ return into account and maps to int.

Comment: for the statement " NullPointerException will occur during auto-boxing" - I think it could be during unboxing, not auto-boxing.